# How to draw light cones between curves

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw the light cones between the geodesic curves, but I can't do this with matplotlib.
The light cones are regions between the outgoin and ingoing geodesics.
My goal is to reproduce the figure that contains the light cones, but the only command I know in matplotlib to paint regions between curves is Fill Between, but I can't reproduce it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 8.0, 0.0001)

geod_out =  (x + 2*np.log(np.abs(x/(2)-1)))
geod_in  = -(x + 2*np.log(np.abs(x/(2)-1)))


for u in np.arange(-20, 20, 2):
    ax.plot(x, geod_out+u ,color='green',linestyle='-.')
    ax.plot(x, geod_in+u ,color='green')


ax.set_xlim(0,8)
ax.set_ylim(-5,5)
ax.grid()

#fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

[image]

Comment: If you explain what light cones are, every matplotlib expert could help, if you don't only matplotlib AND light cones experts (probably a rare combination) would.

Comment: Forgive me. Now maybe my objective is more  clearer.